# Adjusting the size of the text in an prinft command in C

Tags: c, text, printf

I want to make a header for my C programm but I cant find a way to make my Text bigger. Its just one line and not the whole code.

I tried whith those commands: "\033[1;33m" and it didnt work.
I am using my Windows Terminal for executing.

Comment: Your terminal has to support it

Comment: Windows API has [SetCurrentConsoleFontEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setcurrentconsolefontex) function, which works with a [CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-font-infoex) structure, but this sets the size of the font for the whole display. You need to use a GUI to resize specific portions, or create output to a formatted file such as HTML.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make a header for my C programm but I cant find a way to make my Text bigger. It's just one line and not the whole code.

Most terminal emulators don't support variable size or even variable width text; they use a monospaced typeface with a certain number of rows and columns. `printf()` just writes to standard output, which is essentially a file.

If you're using some kind of terminal that does happen to support different sized text, you're going to have to dig into the docs for that and figure out what sort of escape codes you can send to control that, similar to using escape codes to send [ANSI codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to control colors. In any case, `printf()` has no role to play in that -- it just makes its substitutions and sends the resulting string along to the output.